# Aceeder a un modelo de manera dinamica django

Tags: python, django

Quiero realizar lo siguiente
declaro una variable que contenga el nombre del modelo y travez de esas variable ejecutar las consultas sobre ese modelo
ejemplo
modelo = "Persona"
modelo.objects.all()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría usar un diccionario para ayudarte, de esta forma:

```
modelos = {
    'persona': Persona,
    'animal': Animal,
    # ... otros modelos
}

modelo = 'persona'  # esta sería la llave
modelos[modelo].objects.all()
```

Espero que sea de gran ayuda

Comment: gracias no se me habia ocurrido de esa forma